# Deleting FB album via API call

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I've google it and also looked some related questions here in SO, but didn't found an answer. Is there any way to delete an album from FB via Graph API call. I'm making `DELETE` request to `https://graph.facebook.com/ALBUM_ID` with corresponding access token, but it returns me the following: `(#200) Application does not have the capability to make this API call.`

Comment: I've found a bug in the FB bug list: https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/125524667559003?browse=search_4f1ff99bb1efa1c05232430
I think this is the same issue.

Comment: This bug deals with deleting photos - not albums.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just as the error says - your application can not perform these actions.  In actual fact - no applications can delete photo albums.  It is a *limitation by design* of the API.
If anyone finds some evidence to prove me wrong - PLEASE dont keep it to yourself! ;)

Comment: but the same issue exists for photos and FB accepts that as a bug, that's why I think that this is a bug regarding FB albums

Comment: The same "issue" exists also for deleting users - doesn't mean its related.  Deleting albums is simply not possible (at this stage).

Comment: lol, I can't delete users too.  But seriously, remember, your app can only delete the items that app created.  If a user creates a deletable object using the FB GUI, your app cannot delete it.  If a user using a different app creates a deletable object,  your app cannot delete it.  If your app creates a deletable object, then your app can delete it.  :)

Comment: @DMCS I understand that, I just wanted to know if the album is deletable and as I see, the app cannot delete album that has been created via that app...