# Can't delete album with Facebook graph API

Tags: php, wordpress, facebook-graph-api

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Deleting FB album via API call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002920/deleting-fb-album-via-api-call)

I have a problem with deleting albums with Facebook graph although I can delete photos form my albums (I tested it and it works correctly).

Why can I delete photos and can't delete albums? Is this a limitation of the  Facebook graph API or does it requires a specific permission?

I use this code in deleting objects and it works with photos

```
$graph_url = 'https://graph.facebook.com/'.$object_id.'?method=DELETE&'
. 'access_token='. $access_token;

$opts = array('http' =>
  array(
    'method'        => 'DELETE',
    'header'        => 'Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
    'ignore_errors' => true
  )
);

$context  = stream_context_create( $opts );
$result = json_decode( file_get_contents( $graph_url, false, $context) );
```

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What does the `$result` variable contain after the call?

Comment: related - [Deleting FB album via API call](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9002920/deleting-fb-album-via-api-call/9003559#9003559) (you might not like the answer there though :)

Comment: it returns (Application does not have the capability to make this API call), yes i saw it but i am confusing, why i can delete photos and can't delete albums?

Comment: because the you dun have enough permission to perform the api calls?

Comment: Simply because that is a limitation that Facebook decided to enforce. It's their choice what features to allow us to use. This has nothing to do with permissions. In the same way that you can not change your profile picture with the API you can not delete albums. It **doesn't say** "Application does not have the permissions". It says "Application does not have the **capability**".

Comment: @ajr - nope. There is no related permissions for deleting albums. It simply can not be done via their API.

Comment: @moh - In the future, please include any error messages you are getting in your post. Posing the complete error and its message will really help us figure out whats going wrong.  :)

Comment: fine, thanks alot guys, i got the message :)